# How to explain different voltage and symmetry?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

Imagine a magnet is falling along the axis of a uniform metal ring, there is an Eddy current in the ring due to changing magnetic flux and the direction of the current is determined by Lenz's law. Take two points on the ring on each end of the same diameter, let's call them A and B. Current flows from A to B it means A has higher voltage than B, then current flows from B to A, so B has higher voltage than A! I am missing something here; can you please help me understand this? What is voltage between A and B (suppose we have perfect symmetry).

Answer (score 5):

There are two concepts of "voltage between two points $a,b$" in use.

One is dependent on the path chosen: it is based on the integral of total electric field, through the chosen path $\gamma$ joining the points $a,b$:

$$
\text{voltage_v1} = U_{\gamma} = \int_\gamma \mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf s.
$$

This clearly depends on the choice of the path, not only on the points $a,b$. In your example, when two close points $a$, $b$ are assumed, then the integral will be zero when direct joining line is chosen, and will have non-zero value when the closed loop is chosen.

The other (and a lot less confusing) concept of voltage is that it is difference of electric potential $V$. Electric potential can be always defined based on the conservative part of the electric field, and the most usual way is to assume it is given by the Coulomb integral of charge distribution, irrespective of presence of induced field:

$$
V(\mathbf x) = \int K\frac{\rho(\mathbf x')}{|\mathbf x- \mathbf x'|}~d^3\mathbf x'.
$$

This way, drop of potential when going from $a$ to $b$ is function of the points $a,b$ only (and the chosen positive direction - here, from $a$ to $b$).

$$
\text{voltage_v2} = U_{a\to b} = \text{potential drop when going from $a$ to $b$} = V(a) - V(b).
$$

This concept of voltage is used not only in electrostatics, but also in the theory and practice of AC circuits. E.g. voltage on a *perfect* inductor is $LdI/dt$, which *does not* depend on the choice of path, only on the endpoints (usually chosen to be terminals of the inductor).

In your scenario with falling magnet, the magnet produces induced electric field, which causes *induced EMF* in the ring (or a pipe), which drives current there. But contribution of this induced field to conservative electric field is zero, so it changes nothing in the electric potential field and thus no change in voltages.

However, in addition to induced electric field, moving magnet may also bring in its own (very weak, proportional to velocity) conservative electric field. Even if the magnet is not charged in its own frame of reference, it may carry charge distribution in frames where it is moving. This kind of motion-induced charge density on the magnet is non-zero wherever magnetization current $\mathbf J_M$ has a component in line of the magnet velocity $\mathbf v$ (if the component is opposite to $\mathbf v$, then the charge density is negative). This can usually happen on parts of magnet's surface, where there is non-zero magnetization current.

For example, if magnet in shape of a short cylinder falls in the pipe sideways (poles facing the walls), then one half of the magnet's side mantle carries positive charge, and the opposite half carries negative charge, and this means there is conservative electric field due to this charge distribution. This means electric potential of air near one half side of the magnet will be different than potential of the air near the opposite half side.

However, as the pipe is conductive, there won't be much difference of potential in the pipe due to this - charge distribution on the pipe will adapt and create mirror charge that cancels magnet's conservative electric field in the pipe conductor.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. However, its in a language higher than my level. Based on your answer and Rich006's answer, I have come up with a simple explanation (my level of understanding). Here it is: every small element of the ring can be considered as a voltage source V and resistance R. Kirchhoff's law holds for point A & B on the ring; Va =V - RI + Vb. From symmetry we know Va = Vb, so V=RI. So, we can do the same thing for any other two pints and conclude the ring is a equipotential surface. It is still interesting to me to know we can have current on an equipotential surface.

Comment: Your equation is valid, when $V$ is the induced EMF due to the magnet, I would not call it voltage, because that is better reserved for the difference $V_a-V_b$, which is zero here. The current can be present in equipotential body, because there are other forces pushing the current against resistance, not merely gradient of potential. Namely, here it is the induced electric field.

Comment: It's not correct to consider elements of the ring as small sources of potential difference.  If that were true, then you could add up all the small potential differences from A all the way back around to A and you'd get a potential difference between A and A, which can't be (hence your original question).  You can't use Kirchhoff's law here because it only applies to potential _differences_, i.e. changes in potential, as you follow a closed path.  Those changes don't exist in this situation because potential is not defined for electric fields that are caused by changing magnetic fields.

Comment: @Rich006 the original Kirchhoff's second circuital law can be used here, because it states sum of all emfs acting in a closed path is equal to $RI$; this original formulation is not about differences of potential. Only the modern formulation (KVL) is about differences of potential, and that is useless here as those differences either are all zero due to symmetry, or we don't know them.

Answer (score 3):

Voltage is a difference in electric potential between two points.  However, electric potential is only defined for electrostatic fields, i.e. fields due to separated positive and negative charge.  In the case of a moving magnet, there is indeed an electric field induced in the nearby conductor, but it is not an electrostatic field.

Put another way, there are two ways to generate electric fields: separated electric charge, and changing magnetic fields.  Only the first way brings about an electric potential.

Edit: I should add that in your example there is an emf generated in the ring.  This example shows that emf is not always associated with voltage.

Comment: Thank you, what would be the reading of a voltmeter on A and B?

Comment: Electric potential can be also defined in presence of any electric field, as the Coulomb potential of the charge distribution $\rho = \epsilon_0 \nabla\cdot \mathbf E$. Or as the potential associated via the conservative component of electric field $\mathbf E_C$ (Helmholtz theorem). However, this does not make your answer incorrect. Indeed induced electric field due to moving magnet in such a symmetric situation does not imply any gradient of potential in the plane perpendicular to the motion; electric potential may be constant throughout the cross-section.

Comment: @Ebi This is a very fascinating question. If I'm not mistaken, it turns out that the voltmeter would depend on the orientation and arrangement of its probes. There is apparently some internet controversy over whether Kirchhoff's voltage law holds (or rather whether it can be applied) in these cases.

Comment: @Ebi ordinary voltmeter probe wires are not shielded, so the reading will depend on net EMF induced in the measurement circuit, and that depends on position of the wires and voltmeter in space; if you wind one of the probing wires $n$ times around the region where magnetic flux changes, then EMF in the measurement circuit will increase $n$ times and so will the voltmeter reading. If you use oscilloscope probes with a good shielding instead, induced EMF effect on the oscilloscope voltage reading will be decreased, but still not completely cancelled out.

Comment: That's why to measure potential difference reliably, one has to shield the wires and avoid creating loops or even a single loop through which magnetic flux changes in time. Consequently to make measurement as accurate as possible, both wires should be placed as close to each other as possible (to make the magnetic flux through the measurement circuit as small as possible).

Comment: @Maximal Ideal and @ Rich006 please see my comment in Ján Lalinský reply. Thank you.